# Laravel : How do I use factories to seed models in a specific pattern?

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I have a model which stores persons addresses.
A person can have multiple addresses with the following conditions :

- There has to be one address marked as permanent.
- There has to be one address marked as current.
- An address can be marked as permanent and current at the same time.
- An address can be neither permanent nor current.

I'm trying to seed the database using factories.

PersonAddressFactory :

```
$factory->define(PersonAddress::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'Address' => $faker->buildingNumber . ',' . $faker->streetName . ',' . $faker->streetAddress,
        'Landmark' => $faker->optional()->words(3, true),
        'CityID' => App\Entities\City::inRandomOrder()->first()->CityID,
        'PostalCode' => $faker->postcode,
        'IsPermanent' => ???
        'IsCurrent' => ???
    ];
});
```

Seeder :

```
public function run() {
    $no_of_persons = (int)$this->command->ask('How many persons do you want to create?', 10);
    $this->command->info("Seeding {$no_of_persons} persons");
    $persons = factory(App\Entities\Person::class, $no_of_persons)->create();
    $this->command->info('Persons Created!');

    // Creating addresses for persons
    $this->command->info('Creating Addresses for persons');

    $persons->each(
        function ($person) {
            factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, rand(1, 5))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
        });

    $this->command->info('Addresses Created!');

}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :

Taking hint from [Erkan Özkök](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518065/9645846) answer I have updated the code to make use of factory states, this is the final code.

PersonAddressFactory :

```
$factory->define(PersonAddress::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'Address' => $faker->buildingNumber . ',' . $faker->streetName . ',' . $faker->streetAddress,
        'Landmark' => $faker->optional()->words(3, true),
        'CityID' => App\Entities\City::inRandomOrder()->first()->CityID,
        'PostalCode' => $faker->postcode,
        'IsPermanent' => '0',
        'IsCurrent' => '0',
    ];
});

$factory->state(PersonAddress::class, 'permanent', ['IsPermanent' => '1']);
$factory->state(PersonAddress::class, 'current', ['IsCurrent' => '1']);
$factory->state(PersonAddress::class, 'permanent_and_current', ['IsPermanent' => '1', 'IsCurrent' => '1']);
```

Seeder :

```
public function run() {
    $no_of_persons = (int)$this->command->ask('How many persons do you want to create?', 10);
    $this->command->info("Seeding {$no_of_persons} persons");
    $persons = factory(App\Entities\Person::class, $no_of_persons)->create();
    $this->command->info('Persons Created!');

    // Creating addresses for persons
    $this->command->info('Creating Addresses for persons');

    $persons->each(
        function ($person) {
            if (rand(1, 2) == 1) {
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class)->state('permanent')->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class)->state('current')->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
            }
            else {
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class)->state('permanent_and_current')->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
            }
            factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, rand(0, 3))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
        });

    $this->command->info('Addresses Created!');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define factory types separately

```
$factory->define(PersonAddress::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'Address' => $faker->buildingNumber . ',' . $faker->streetName . ',' . $faker->streetAddress,
        'Landmark' => $faker->optional()->words(3, true),
        'CityID' => App\Entities\City::inRandomOrder()->first()->CityID,
        'PostalCode' => $faker->postcode,
        'IsPermanent' => false,
        'IsCurrent' => false,
    ];
});

$factory->defineAs(PersonAddress::class, 'permanent', function (Faker $faker) {
    $address = $factory->raw(PersonAddress::class);

    return array_merge($address, ['IsPermanent' => true, 'IsCurrent' => false]);
});

$factory->defineAs(PersonAddress::class, 'current', function (Faker $faker) {
    $address = $factory->raw(PersonAddress::class);

    return array_merge($address, ['IsPermanent' => false, 'IsCurrent' => true]);
});

$factory->defineAs(PersonAddress::class, 'permanent_and_current', function (Faker $faker) {
    $address = $factory->raw(PersonAddress::class);

    return array_merge($address, ['IsPermanent' => true, 'IsCurrent' => true]);
});
```

And use them for generating randomly

```
public function run() {
    $no_of_persons = (int)$this->command->ask('How many persons do you want to create?', 10);
    $this->command->info("Seeding {$no_of_persons} persons");
    $persons = factory(App\Entities\Person::class, $no_of_persons)->create();
    $this->command->info('Persons Created!');

    // Creating addresses for persons
    $this->command->info('Creating Addresses for persons');

    $persons->each(
        function ($person) {
            if (rand(1, 2) == 1) {
                // make different current and permanent addresses
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, 'permanent', rand(1, 5))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, 'current', rand(1, 5))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
            } else {
                // make same address as permanent and current
                factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, 'permanent_and_current', rand(1, 5))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
            }

            // make some random addresses
            factory(App\Entities\PersonAddress::class, rand(0, 3))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);
        });

    $this->command->info('Addresses Created!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have used your answer as a source and updated the code to make use of factory states feature available in newer version of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way would be forcing an address that is current and permanent first, then seed random.

```
use App\Entities\PersonAddress;

// ...

$persons->each(function ($person) {
    factory(PersonAddress::class)->create(['PersonId' => $person->PersonID, 'permanent' => true, 'current' => true]);
    factory(PersonAddress::class, rand(0, 5))->create(['PersonId' => $person->PersonID]);
});
```

Or the other way would be seeding like you did, then check if there's a permanent and a current in the database, if not, then create one.

```
$persons->each(function ($person) {
    factory(PersonAddress::class, rand(1, 5))->create(['PersonID' => $person->PersonID]);

    $permanentCount = PersonAddress::where('PersonID', $person->PersonId)->where('permanent', true)->count();
    $currentCount = PersonAddress::where('PersonID', $person->PersonId)->where('current', true)->count();

    if (! $permanentCount || ! $currentCount) {
        factory(PersonAddress::class, rand(1, 5))->create([
            'PersonID' => $person->PersonID,
            'permanent' => $permanentCount < 1,
            'current' => $currentCount < 1
        ]);
    }
});
```